# Распознание даты по фото. С помощью чего можно более-менее неплохо распознать цифры на картинке?

Tags: opencv

Подскажите, с помощью чего можно более-менее неплохо распознать цифры на картинке? Я пробовал pytesseract, но он не очень справляется ([Пример 1](https://sun9-35.userapi.com/c854528/v854528547/170375/YXIvOI7WTAI.jpg), [Пример 2](https://sun9-4.userapi.com/c855524/v855524547/16c9ac/NLep8djahFY.jpg))

[image]

[image]

Может кто-то знает с помощью чего распознает Google Translate?У них это хорошо выходит ([Пример 3](https://sun9-20.userapi.com/c853516/v853516547/16add6/VW7X77E0gCQ.jpg))

[image]

Comment: можете использовать ui path shodio и создать робота чтобы читал цифры из картинки и превращать их в текст.

Comment: Есть огромное количество ботов в Телеграме большинство работает на основе гугл транслейта. Разве нет API для работы с гуглом?

Comment: Можно посмотреть в сторону Azure Cognitive Services или решений на базе этого сервиса - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-recognizing-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианты навскидку

### Google Vision

[Google Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) - специальный облачный сервис, производительность много выше, чем этого можно достичь на обычном компе/телефоне, так что качество распознавания безусловно выше. Распознает не только символы, но также и много чего еще, типа: лица, нудистику и проч.

Сервис [платный](https://cloud.google.com/vision/pricing?hl=ru). Ориентировочно будет стоить в районе $1.5 за 1000.

Поддерживается REST, Ruby, Python, Java, Node.JS, C#, Go, PHP

### ABBYY

Можно также использовать [Abbyy Cloud OCR](https://www.ocrsdk.com/) - качество я думаю будет не хуже гугловского. Цены [смотрите сами](https://www.ocrsdk.com/plans-and-pricing/)

Поддерживаются: Ruby, Python, Java, JavaScript, .NET, PHP